# How to get the received signal in kernel threads

Tags: kernel-module

I call the function signal_pending() in my kernel thread. When return true, i want to get the
signal.my code is as follows:
    `sigset = &current->signal->shared_pending.signal;`
but the value is zero.where is my mistake in ?